# Does Elementary OS supports 4k displays?

Tags: system-installation, graphic-drivers, drivers, hidpi

Just try to install OS using laptop with 4k display. It will be not possible to install the system, because installer interface gets broken.

Tested on Dell Inspiron 7548.

Answer (score 1):

elementary OS does not currently fully support HiDPI displays